# How to show different alerts without using delegate in iOS?

Tags: ios6

i have  created an image view which was added to a button, i.e.) set of images were added to the image view which the array was added to the loop and same for the button, image were centered and paging were enabled, so images were now appears in a sequence with button on it , these were added to the scorllview while scrolling is enabled and by selecting each image an alert should appear like first image, second image,etc. My question is: but the alert should appears differently without using alert view delegate, how to show different alert by selecting on each image?

```
int buttonXPostion = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < [_array count]; i++)
{
    buttonXPostion  = i*frameWidth;
    wallPaperButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonXPostion,7,frameWidth, frameheight)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,frameWidth,frameheight)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[_array objectAtIndex:i]];
    [wallPaperButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [wallPaperButton addSubview:imageView];
    [scrollImage addSubview:wallPaperButton];
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: first set tag of UIButton wallPaperButton by using wallPaperButton.tag=i;

Comment: And than implement method as per shown in my answer.

Comment: if you have any issue related to my answer then you can comment here

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda where to find the answer?

Comment: i already added my answer... see below answer section

Comment: have you find answer or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be this will help you..

```
-(IBAction)imageSelected:(id)sender
{
    if(sender.tag==0)
    {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"First Image Button Pressed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         alert.tag=sender.tag;
    }
    else if(sender.tag==1)
    {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Second Image Button Pressed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         alert.tag=sender.tag;
    }

    ........   ///   implement if condition as per tag you require
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ya i have got done! By setting tag for the button,

```
    wallPaperButton.tag=i;

-(IBAction)imageSelected:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    switch (button.tag) {
        case 0:{
            NSString *message=@"FirstImage";
            alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            break;}
        case 1:{
            NSString *message=@"SecondImage";
            alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            break;}
        case 2:{
            NSString *message=@"ThirdImage";
            alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            break;}
        case 3:{
            NSString *message=@"FourthImage";
            alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            break;}
        case 4:{
            NSString *message=@"FifthImage";
            alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            break;}
        case 5:{
            NSString *message=@"sixthImage";
            alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            break;}
        default:
            break;
    }
  [alert show];
}
```